# jQuery Validate plugin custom messages with fieldnames

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm currently using the jQuery Validate plugin for my input validation. 
It is used within a tableview with records which has editable fields.

When I push submit I want everything to be validated and the errors shown in the general errorContainer.

The problem is that I have multiple rows. So when I edit a row's emailaddress than it tells me that the e-mailadres field is required. But when I change to emailaddresses I can see the error 2 times.

What I want is the following:

- The emailaddress for user1 is required
- The emailaddress for user2 is required

Instead of:

- The emailaddres is required
- The emailaddres is required

The emailadress is required

User1 and User2 is a non editable field in the row.

Can someone help me out?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>user1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>user1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="email"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The input fields need to be validated when the user enters submit with the following jQuery snippet

```
$("#selfManagementForm").validate(
  {
   errorLabelContainer:"#validationErrors",
   wrapper:"li"
  }).form();
```

Comment: Please provide some code snippets.

Comment: I've edited my original post @Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) area of the validate documentation, you can provide a `messages` object to the validate call.  To make this work, you really should have `name="user1"` and `name="user2"` in your input elements, so they can be referenced by the messages object:

```
$("#selfManagementForm").validate(
{
  errorLabelContainer:"#validationErrors",
  wrapper:"li",
  messages: {
    user1: 'The emailaddress for user1 is required',
    user2: 'The emailaddress for user2 is required'
  }
});
```

Comment: But i have multiple fields in each row. I also have different validation settings for each field. A row has multiple input fields: email, phone, last name, ...

Comment: Right?  could you set the name to say `<input type="text" class="email" name="user1_email">` ?  Then your message keys would be `user1_email` and `user2_email`?